# C# TrimStart with string array parameter: TrimStart(params string[] trimStrings)

Tags: c#, string, extension-methods

I'm looking for String extension methods for `TrimStart(params string[] trimStrings)` 
and `TrimEnd(params string[] trimStrings)` that accept a string array parameter.

Methods should function like default `TrimStart(params char[] trimChars)` and `TrimEnd(params char[] trimChars)` methods. Ie. the intention is to trim all occurrences of each (exactly matching) string from trimStrings array.

It would be also nice to add an option of case-insensitive trimming.

What would be the optimal way to implement such method?
Please see my try below.

Comment: Not a code request site. You'll have to at least try to implement them first.

Comment: I think you are looking for rentacoder.com.

Comment: I have changed the question at the end.

Comment: That still doesn't makes it a good question for SO without your attempt though.

Comment: Do you understand what your really want? How it should really work? What should be the result of "trimmingDATA".TrimStart("trim", "trimming")?

Comment: Doh, why are you people are so discouraging for new users??

Comment: @eugene, despite your slightly offensive tone, it was a valuable clue. Thanks

Comment: I would not say that it was offensive. Just your question was a bit too unclear and it was difficult for me to comprehend the desired behaviour. So, no offense intended.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution:

```
public static string TrimStart(this string target, StringComparison comparisonType, params string[] trimStrings)
{
    string result = target;
    if (trimStrings == null)
        return result;
    var _trimStrings = trimStrings.OrderByDescending(t => t.Length).ToList();
    bool trimmed = false;
    do
    {
        trimmed = false;
        foreach (var trimString in _trimStrings)
        {
            while (result.StartsWith(trimString, comparisonType))
            {
                result = result.Substring(trimString.Length);
                trimmed = true;
            }
        }
    } while (trimmed);
    return result;
}

public static string TrimEnd(this string target, StringComparison comparisonType, params string[] trimStrings)
{
    string result = target;
    if (trimStrings == null)
        return result;
    var _trimStrings = trimStrings.OrderByDescending(t => t.Length).ToList();
    bool trimmed = false;
    do
    {
        trimmed = false;
        foreach (var trimString in _trimStrings)
        {
            while (result.EndsWith(trimString, comparisonType))
            {
                result = result.Substring(0, result.Length - trimString.Length);
                trimmed = true;
            }
        }
    } while (trimmed);
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Now that you've shown your approach, what is the problem with it? You should mention the problem. Does it work as expected, is it slow, unreadable, do you have any issues? Otherwise it's not a real question but maybe a candidate for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/.

Answer (score 1):

Even if your questions is not really a question but a specification i've given it a try.

Here's my `TrimStart`, you are free to write the `TrimEnd` yourself ;)

```
public static string TrimStart(this string str, StringComparison comparison = StringComparison.CurrentCulture, params string[] trimStrings)
{
    if (str == null) return null;

    // Check the longest strings first and check only relevant strings
    List<string> orderedTrimStrings = trimStrings
        .Where(ts => !String.IsNullOrEmpty(ts) && ts.Length <= str.Length)
        .OrderByDescending(ts => ts.Length)
        .ToList();  

    int minLength = orderedTrimStrings.Last().Length;
    for (int i = 0; i + minLength <= str.Length;)
    {
        string longestTrim = orderedTrimStrings
            .Where(ts => i + ts.Length <= str.Length)
            .FirstOrDefault(ts => str.Substring(i, ts.Length).Equals(ts, comparison));
        if (longestTrim == null)
            return str.Substring(i);
        else
            i += longestTrim.Length;
    }
    return "";
}
```

Note that it's not really tested, here is one sample that works:

```
string hw = "Hello World";
hw = hw.TrimStart(StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase, "hello", " ");
// "World"
```